# For the exterior and interior multiplications $e$, resp. $i$: $e(\tau) i(X) + i(X) e(\tau) = \tau(X) Id$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, exterior-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and $V^*$ its dual. For $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\omega \in \bigwedge^{k}(V^{*})$, $\tau \in V^*$ then $e(\tau)\omega= \tau \wedge \omega$ is the exterior multiplication. For $X \in V$, the interior multiplication is defined as:
$i(X) \omega(v_1,...,v_{k-1}) = \omega(X,v_1,...,v_{k-1})$.

Now in the lecture we had a formula which wasn't proved:
$e(\tau)i(X) + i(X)e(\tau) = \tau(X)\operatorname{Id}$.

Is there an elegant, maybe even coordinate-free way to prove this ?

Comment: I suggest that you try yourself to find a proof using just the definitions, a basis of the tangent space and its dual basis. Note that this is a purely a fact in multilinear algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the fact that
$$
\iota_X \left( \alpha\wedge \beta\right) = (\iota_X \alpha)\wedge \beta + (-1)^k\alpha \wedge (\iota_X \beta),
$$
where $\alpha$ is $a$ $k$-form and $\beta$ any differential form (see [the wikipedia article for interior product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product)).
This easily follows from the definition on terms of the form $\lambda e^{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e^{i_k}$, the general case on $\Lambda^k V^*$ following by linearity.

If $\tau$ is a $1$-form and $\omega$ any differential form, we have
\begin{align}
\iota_X(\tau\wedge \omega) &= (\iota_X\tau)\wedge \omega + (-1)^1 \tau \wedge (\iota_X\omega) \\
&= \tau(X)\omega - \tau\wedge (\iota_X\omega).
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
\iota_X(\tau\wedge \omega) + \tau\wedge (\iota_X\omega) = \tau(X) \omega,
$$
that is, with your notations,
$$
e(\tau)\circ i(X) + i(X)\circ e(\tau) = \tau(X) \mathrm{Id}.
$$

Comment: Thank you ! That was very helpful